# Unity 2D Fighting Game Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2d fighting camera. I want the camera to focus on 2 fighters and then zoom in/out to make sure they are both on the screen. Using the post below, I was able to get this camera to work horizontally:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/126184/fighting-game-camera.html

The original script is the following

```cs
float margin = 1.5f; // space between screen border and nearest fighter    
private float z0; // coord z of the fighters plane
private float zCam; // camera distance to the fighters plane
private float wScene; // scene width
private Transform f1; // fighter1 transform
private Transform f2; // fighter2 transform
private float xL; // left screen X coordinate
private float xR; // right screen X coordinate

public void calcScreen(Transform p1, Transform p2)
{
    // Calculates the xL and xR screen coordinates 
    if (p1.position.x < p2.position.x)
    {
        xL = p1.position.x - margin;
        xR = p2.position.x + margin;
    }
    else
    {
        xL = p2.position.x - margin;
        xR = p1.position.x + margin;
    }
}

public void Start()
{
    // find references to the fighters
    f1 = GameObject.Find("Fighter1").transform;
    f2 = GameObject.Find("Fighter2").transform;
    // initializes scene size and camera distance
    calcScreen(f1, f2);
    wScene = xR - xL;
    zCam = transform.position.z - z0;
}

public void Update()
{
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    calcScreen(f1, f2);
    float width = xR - xL;

    if (width > wScene)
    { // if fighters too far adjust camera distance
        pos.z = zCam * width / wScene + z0;
    }

    // centers the camera
    pos.x = (xR + xL) / 2;    

    transform.position = pos;
}
```

Since on my game you can move horizontally and vertically, I modified the code to also adjust when the character moves vertically to this:

```cs
float margin = 1.5f; // space between screen border and nearest fighter
float marginY = 1.5f; // space between screen border and nearest fighter

private float z0; // coord z of the fighters plane
private float zCam; // camera distance to the fighters plane
private float wScene; // scene width
private float hScene; // scene height
private Transform f1; // fighter1 transform
private Transform f2; // fighter2 transform
private float xL; // left screen X coordinate
private float xR; // right screen X coordinate
private float yU; // up screen Y coordinate
private float yD; // down screen Y coordinate

public void calcScreen(Transform p1, Transform p2)
{
    // Calculates the xL and xR screen coordinates 
    if (p1.position.x < p2.position.x)
    {
        xL = p1.position.x - margin;
        xR = p2.position.x + margin;
    }
    else
    {
        xL = p2.position.x - margin;
        xR = p1.position.x + margin;
    }

    if (p1.position.y < p2.position.y)
    {
        yD = p1.position.y - marginY;
        yU = p2.position.y + marginY;
    }
    else
    {
        yD = p2.position.y - marginY;
        yU = p1.position.y + marginY;
    }
}

public void Start()
{
    // find references to the fighters
    f1 = GameObject.Find("Fighter1").transform;
    f2 = GameObject.Find("Fighter2").transform;
    // initializes scene size and camera distance
    calcScreen(f1, f2);
    wScene = xR - xL;
    hScene = yU - yD;
    zCam = transform.position.z - z0;
}

public void Update()
{
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    calcScreen(f1, f2);
    float width = xR - xL;
    float height = yU - yD;

    if (width > wScene)
    { // if fighters too far adjust camera distance
        pos.z = zCam * width / wScene + z0;
    }
    else if (height > hScene)
    { // if fighters too far adjust camera distance
        pos.z = zCam * height / hScene + z0;
    }

    // centers the camera
    pos.x = (xR + xL) / 2;
    pos.y = (yU + yD) / 2;

    transform.position = pos;
}
```

This works when the character only moves horizontally or vertically, if it moves both horizontally and vertically it doesn't work anymore. Also, the vertical movement doesn't work appropriately when the 2 fighters are far away. The camera zooms in even thought they are far from each other but they are close in terms of the height.

I feel like I need to change the code to look at both `x` and `y` at the same time. It feels like I'm considering and `x` separately.

I have been stuck on this for a while now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your else statement is the reason your vertical scaling is being removed. You should change your if block in Update to this.

```
if (width > wScene)
{ // if fighters too far adjust camera distance
    pos.z = zCam * width / wScene + z0;
}

if (height > hScene)
{ // if fighters too far adjust camera distance
    pos.z = Mathf.Max(zCam * height / hScene + z0, pos.z);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry this didn't work either. The camera is not zooming in and out as the characters are close to each other